# How to change the parent value, affect the children value between 2 table in SQL

Tags: sql, database-design

For example,  if there are two tables:

```
Table 1: Company
which have a attribute : status

Table 2 : Employee
which have a attribute : status
```

If table 1 attribute change to 1/0, the table 2 have to follow, however, if table 2 change to 1/0, there should be no action for table 1. How to construct that?

Comment: status can not be the primary key in table 1

Comment: yes, I have comapnyid in employee table alerady, what is that status table should look like ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create database trigger on update of table 1.
If you use MySQL you can read about it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Thanks, can I construct it in database structure?

Comment: You can create trigger as other sql commands (insert, update). Just write `CREATE TRIGGER ...` etc. on the table which you need.

Comment: so is it better compare to store status in a separate table?

Comment: It depends on your design. If you can't use one status from one table, you can use both and update one depending on other. I'd just update without comparison.

Comment: There should be two status and 1 for company 1 for employee....it seems trigger is the best approach?

Comment: You can do it in the backend code if you like. It's up to you.